# How can I run jQuery Codes (google maps)?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, google-maps

Using the code below, i want to add a map to my page. However, when i copy-paste them, it's shown in body like a paragraph. Could you please help me?

```
$("#test").gmap3({
    map:{
      address:"POURRIERES, FRANCE",
      options:{
        zoom:4,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE,
        mapTypeControl: true,
        mapTypeControlOptions: {
          style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU
        },
        navigationControl: true,
        scrollwheel: true,
        streetViewControl: true
      }
    }
  });
```

Comment: add <script> tags around your code?

Comment: i've added them. i'm workin with c#, what could i do? Thanks.

Comment: I think you have to make your self a bit clearer where do you put this code? You cannot put it in a .cs file in .NET. Please elaborate...

Comment: actually i'm trying it asp.net. in masterpage but the language is c#.

Comment: Do you have jquery libraries included in your page?  Along with in your project?  Also, do you have google maps api included in your page possibly .aspx or mvc view?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to take a step back and review the basics of HTML.  The javascript code you have needs to be enclosed in `<script>` tags and added to the html page.

A detailed explanation of the basics is at - [Google Maps in HTML, ASP.NET, PHP, JSP etc. with ease](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20590/Google-Maps-in-HTML-ASP-NET-PHP-JSP-etc-with-ease).

You are editing html to add the content, so it is independent of c#.